# Sublime Lightning plugin seems to not work anymore

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps, sublime

Has anyone been able to fetch lightning component using Dave Caroll's Sublime Lightning plugin? It worked like a charm before but now it can't fetch any more components created in SF. If I create the components using the sublime lightning plugin, then when I reopen Sublime the next day, the error of duplicating id will pop up. If I create the components in Salesforce, the plugin only creates .manifest file (usually, it's supposed to fetch the component and the associated style, controller, and helper).
Also, I do all of my lightning components in sandbox

Comment: I'm investigating this today.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this behavior.  Can you make sure to update both the plugin and the CLI?  The plugin can be updated by using CMD+SHIFT+P then typing Update and selecting Upgrade Package.  For the CLI re-download it from Force-cli.herokuapp.com.

Comment: the plugin is up to date and force cli version is 0.22.28. I tried to create a new salesforce developer account just to test and everything seems to work fine in production. The problem happens only in my working sandbox so I don't know if there's any permission issues that may prevent force cli from grabbing the components. If that's the case, I'm the sandbox's system admin so I can totally change any settings.

Comment: OS? OS Version? Recent upgrades to OS?

Comment: Windows 8 64bit. It worked well before with my current windows 8 os.

Comment: This issue still seems to be happening to me and my team. Force-CLI and Lightning plugin are the latest versions as of 11 Aug 2015: - OS: MacOS 10.10.4
- Sublime: 3083 - Force-CLI: v0.22.30
- Lightning plugin: 1.2.6 The culprit might be an empty "Files" list in the .manifest when 'fetching lightning' (Lightning -> Fetch -> Lightning). For example, the manifest for a Lightning app created in the Developer Console and fetched via the plugin looks like this: {"Name":"XXXTestApp","Id":"0AbB000000007xiKAA","Files":[]} even though there is a "XXXTestApp.app" file in my org with some content in it. A